# Como fazer uma string ser "tranformada em numero"

Tags: c, string, ascii

Tenho um exercício para fazer com que o usuário digite uma palavra e ela seja transformada por seus números correspondentes da tabela ASCII.

**EXEMPLO**: `sara` iria imprimir `115 97 114 97`

esse é o código:

OBS: coloquei um valor fixo no vetor apenas para teste.
O resultado disso esta gerando dois problemas:

- na hora de dar os valores ele *PULA* o primeiro valor (tipo imprime `ara` e não `sara`)
- E também imprime uns números estranhos tipo -14

  ```
  {
    int i;
    char texto[15] ;

    printf("digite uma palavra");
    gets(texto);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%c",texto);

    for (i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
      printf("Valor do elemento %d da string = %d\n",i, texto[i]);
    }

    getch();
  }
  ```

Comment: Depende da linguagem de programação. Parece que você está a usar C, confere? Se sim, pode por C nas tags?

Comment: sim. Me desculpe, esqueci de comentar que é em C

Comment: resolvi já, será que eu preciso falar aqui o que eu fiz?

Comment: O ideal é postar como resposta, para que outros possam saber como você resolveu e, de preferência, sua linha de pensamento em como resolveu

Comment: O `scanf` tem de ser com `%s` e não `%c` e é seriamente desaconselhado o uso de `gets`. O `fflush` também não só é desnecessário como não é garantido que funcione numa stream de entrada e tipicamente só funciona em ambiente windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi , tentando resolver seu problema vou listar algumas funções de conversão de strings que podem ser úteis mas lembre de incluir a biblioteca: strings.h

```
double atof (const char *string);
//Converte uma string em um valor real.
```

```
int atoi (const char *string);
//Converte uma string em um valor imteiro.
```

```
int atol (const char *string);
//Converte uma string em um valor inteiro longo.
```

```
int sprintf (char *string, const *char format,
double number);
//Converte um número em string.
```

Comment: obrigada!! consegui resolver